# Is it possible in Autofac to resolve all services for a type, even if they were registered with a name or key?

Tags: inversion-of-control, autofac

In Autofac one can do the following to get all registered services:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> all = Context.Resolve<IEnumerable<MyClass>>()
```

However, this does not include those which were registered as named services.

Looking at the Autofac source it seems this is because services are queried for resolution based on either a TypedService or a KeyedService.

Is there a way to resolve all services to an IEnumerable, irrespective of whether they were registered with a name or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best option here is to register the items using both the key and the regular 'typed' service:

```
builder.Register<CupOfT>()
    .As<IBeverage>()
    .Keyed<IBeverage>("someKey");
```

You can then just resolve `IEnumerable<IBeverage>` to get the result you're after, while resolving them by key (or name) is also supported.

If you're concerned about maintaining a particular default registration for `IBeverage` just use `PreseveExistingDefaults()` on the others (or make sure your intended default is registered last).

HTH!

Nick

Comment: Quick help followed by delayed response from the OP isn't very zen, huge apologies! I should have mentioned in my question that I'm not necessarily in control of all registrations. This is part of an abstraction above Autofac, in a framework used to build sites (Umbraco 5) so that our framework can be used in 3rd-party solutions which have a business or other dependency on another container or another release of Autofac entirely without our own internal registration code being provider-specific.

Comment: It seems that, with this registration, the components of that `IEnumerable<IBeverage>` are all differ from a component resolved by that name `context.ResolveKeyed<IBeverage>("someKey")`.

Comment: But it can be solved by adding `.SingleInstance()` to your registration.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a method which appears to work; I'd appreciate feedback if there's a built-in way to do this in Autofac. In the below example, the field _context is of type IComponentContext.

```
    public IEnumerable<T> ResolveAll<T>()
    {
        // We're going to find each service which was registered
        // with a key, and for those which match the type T we'll store the key
        // and later supplement the default output with individual resolve calls to those
        // keyed services
        var allKeys = new List<object>();
        foreach (var componentRegistration in _context.ComponentRegistry.Registrations)
        {
            // Get the services which match the KeyedService type
            var typedServices = componentRegistration.Services.Where(x => x is KeyedService).Cast<KeyedService>();
            // Add the key to our list so long as the registration is for the correct type T
            allKeys.AddRange(typedServices.Where(y => y.ServiceType == typeof (T)).Select(x => x.ServiceKey));
        }

        // Get the default resolution output which resolves all un-keyed services
        var allUnKeyedServices = new List<T>(_context.Resolve<IEnumerable<T>>());
        // Add the ones which were registered with a key
        allUnKeyedServices.AddRange(allKeys.Select(key => _context.ResolveKeyed<T>(key)));

        // Return the total resultset
        return allUnKeyedServices;
    }
```

Comment: Rather than using `Resolve()` and `ResolveKeyed()` in here, you might consider using the `ResolveComponent()` method. This will better handle cases where multiple implementations exist for the same service (or with the same key.)

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you can combine the `As<T>()` methods and `Named<T>()` methods as shown below:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ResolveTests()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<ClassA1>().As<IClassA>().Named<IClassA>("1");
        builder.RegisterType<ClassA2>().As<IClassA>().Named<IClassA>("2");
        builder.RegisterType<ClassA3>().As<IClassA>().Named<IClassA>("3");
        var container = builder.Build();

        var allInstances = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IClassA>>();
        allInstances.Count().Should().Be(3);

        container.ResolveNamed<IClassA>("1").Should().BeAssignableTo<ClassA1>();
        container.ResolveNamed<IClassA>("2").Should().BeAssignableTo<ClassA2>();
        container.ResolveNamed<IClassA>("3").Should().BeAssignableTo<ClassA3>();
    }
```

Comment: It seems that, with this registration, the components of `allInstances` are all differ from the components resolved by name `container.ResolveKeyed<IClassA>(...)`.

Comment: But if you supply `.SingleInstance()` to your registration, `allInstances` and `ResolveNamed` instances will be equal.