# Keyed registration with implicit types and no defaults

Tags: autofac

When I register a type with autofac and use `PreserveExistingDefaults`, it registers a default for `T` if no previous registrations for that type exist.  I know this is how it is intended, but is there a way to have it not register a default at all, but still get registered for implicit types?

My use case is that I want to **(1)** force consumers of type `T` to rely on a keyed registration (i.e. throw an exception if `T` is requested without a key filter), and **(2)** I also want those registrations to show up in `IEnumerable<T>` implicit injections.

I saw in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4981702/3525158) that I can just add an `As<T>` registration to accomplish **(2)**, but it also registers a default so I don't get **(1)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not a use case Autofac addresses.

I might suggest that there's a logic flaw in the design anyway. If a developer can't resolve a single `T` without a key, but they can resolve *all* the `T` without keys, then folks will simply work around the problem by resolving all of them and manually choosing the one they want. I would recommend revisiting the requirements so you don't have the situation you describe.

Comment: That's a good point.  I think for my use case, getting and operating on a collection of `T` is valid and I just want to guard against the case where someone asks for a single `T` which should not be valid.  I thought of two solutions, one may be to add a default registration that just throws an exception.  Another is don't use the `As<T>` registration and use this https://dotnetfalcon.com/using-ireadonlydictionary-instead-of-iindex-with-autofac/ to get something I can iterate over.

Comment: I do want to re-address this answer because its something we keep running into with our DI setup that causes unexpected results.  Here's a use-case, say we start with one `T` service and consumers happily depend on `T`.  But then we realize we need a second `T` and consumers should switch over to using `[KeyFilter(id)] T`.  However, we miss one, and now instead of getting a runtime exception, we're just using the wrong `T` service (whichever was registered last).  Is there a way to mitigate this, while still allowing all `T` registrations to show up in `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: (understood that the above is a developer mistake, but it's a really hairy one to track down in a large or distributed codebase and I would love for a fail-fast solution)